# How do I limit the date and time which the value provides

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm working on a serverinfo embed for my bot and I wanted to use `ctx.guild.created_at` for the guild's age, but it outputs `2020-11-21 21:38:57.527000`. I would like to get rid of the time and only keep the date.

Comment: `ctx.guild.created_at[10]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways,

1. use strftime
2. manually split it

```py
# Split
time = str(ctx.guild.created_at).split()[0]
>>> 2020-11-21

# strftime
time = ctx.guild.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
>>> 2020-11-21
```

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: glad i was able to help you :)